Issue with Hilt Application Class: Gradle Dependency Conflict
I'm working on an Android project that runs fine without the following Hilt application class:
package com.app.bestride

import android.app.Application
import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp

@HiltAndroidApp
class BestRideApplication : Application() {
    // Empty for now
}

However, whenever I add this class, I encounter the following error:
Unable to find method ''java.lang.String com.squareup.javapoet.ClassName.canonicalName()''
'java.lang.String com.squareup.javapoet.ClassName.canonicalName()'

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Here's build.gradle file
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid)
    alias(libs.plugins.daggerHilt)
    kotlin("kapt")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.app.bestride"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.app.bestride"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))

    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.compose)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3.android)
    implementation(libs.play.services.maps)
    implementation(libs.maps.compose)
    implementation(libs.hilt.android)
    implementation(libs.firebase.auth.ktx)
    kapt(libs.hilt.android.compiler)
    implementation(libs.androidx.hilt.navigation.compose)

    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
}

// Ensure kapt settings are included
kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}

Here's toml file
    [versions]
agp = "8.3.0"
hiltAndroid = "2.44"
hiltNavigationCompose = "1.2.0"
javapoet = "1.13.0"
kotlin = "1.9.0"
coreKtx = "1.12.0"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.1.5"
espressoCore = "3.5.1"
lifecycleRuntimeKtx = "2.7.0"
activityCompose = "1.8.2"
composeBom = "2023.08.00"
mapsCompose = "4.3.3"
material3Android = "1.2.1"
navigationCompose = "2.7.7"
playServicesMaps = "19.0.0"
firebaseAuthKtx = "23.0.0"

[libraries]
androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtx" }
androidx-hilt-navigation-compose = { module = "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose", version.ref = "hiltNavigationCompose" }
hilt-android = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android", version.ref = "hiltAndroid" }
hilt-android-compiler = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler", version.ref = "hiltAndroid" }
javapoet = { module = "com.squareup:javapoet", version.ref = "javapoet" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
androidx-espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
androidx-lifecycle-runtime-ktx = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleRuntimeKtx" }
androidx-activity-compose = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity-compose", version.ref = "activityCompose" }
androidx-compose-bom = { group = "androidx.compose", name = "compose-bom", version.ref = "composeBom" }
androidx-ui = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui" }
androidx-ui-graphics = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-graphics" }
androidx-ui-tooling = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling" }
androidx-ui-tooling-preview = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling-preview" }
androidx-ui-test-manifest = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-manifest" }
androidx-ui-test-junit4 = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-junit4" }
androidx-material3 = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3" }
androidx-material3-android = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3-android", version.ref = "material3Android" }
androidx-navigation-compose = { group = "androidx.navigation", name = "navigation-compose", version.ref = "navigationCompose" }
maps-compose = { module = "com.google.maps.android:maps-compose", version.ref = "mapsCompose" }
play-services-maps = { group = "com.google.android.gms", name = "play-services-maps", version.ref = "playServicesMaps" }
firebase-auth-ktx = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-auth-ktx", version.ref = "firebaseAuthKtx" }

[plugins]
androidApplication = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
jetbrainsKotlinAndroid = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
daggerHilt = { id = "com.google.dagger.hilt.android", version.ref = "hiltAndroid" }

Steps I've tried:

Cleaning and rebuilding the project.
Invalidating caches and restarting Android Studio.
Re-downloading dependencies and syncing the project.
Stopping and restarting Gradle build processes.
None of these steps have resolved the issue. The project works perfectly without the BestRideApplication class, but adding it causes the above error.

How can I fix this issue?

Please add the build.gradle to the question so we can try simulate.

@JohnWilliams added the build.gradle kindly take a look

Please also provide the parts of your version catalog that are Hilt-related.

@Leviathan can you be more specific about the file? because Hilt has been used in multiple places

@Leviathan added toml file

You only have one version catalog in your project, located in the project's root directy and named libs.versions.toml. That is where the dependencies are defined that you then use in your gradle file. Just middle-click on any of your dependencies (like libs.hilt.android) and you will jump right to it. There are three sections ([versions], [libraries] and [plugins]), and you will find Hilt-related stuff in all three. We need to see these.

@leviathan added it..please check

I cannot reproduce the problem, the code you provided looks fine. Please create a new project and copy all the code from your question to it. In addition you need these three things: 1.) Add the application class to your AndroidManifest.xml 2.) Annotate the MainActivity with @AndroidEntryPoint 3.) Adjust the top-level gradle file to contain the same plugin alias entries as your module gradle file, appended with apply false -- This new project should compile and run just fine. The next step you need to do is then to compare what you did differently in your real project.

If you still cannot fix the problem after you found it, please replace the code in your question with a [mre] that we can use to actually reproduce the problem.

@Leviathan unable to fix it .. is there any other way we could connect?

Sorry, that's not possible. The only way we can help you is if you provide a [mre].

Okay I'll provide the MRE in a few minutes

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

adding alias(libs.plugins.hilt) apply false to module level Gradle file solved the issue.

I had the same issue.
Tried apply false .... well It didn't applied the plugin. I obviously need that plugin for dependency injection to work.
I updated kotlin version to 2.0.21 (currently newest), newest ksp, newest hilt dagger plugin, dependencies - same result.
I also noticed that > Task :app:hiltAggregateDepsDebug FAILED
So by googling that issue i stumbled upon This issue.
Provided answer worked for me.
In short
Add this to all modules that uses hilt.
hilt {
    enableAggregatingTask = false
}

p.s. In case it makes a difference i used ksp instead of kapt
